# show div on wrong field input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script to show a div when the correct input is filled in.
But I would like to show another div as long as the input is filled in wrong..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#inputId').bind('keyup', function () {
    $('#volgende div').hide();
    var divName = this.value;
    if (divName) {
        $('#volgende #' + divName).show();
    }
});
});
```

**JSfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/QwCQm/

I should add an 'else' somewhere but I can't seem to make it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#inputId').bind('keyup', function () {
        $('#volgende div').hide();
        var divName = $(this).val(),
            div     = $('#volgende #' + divName);

        if (div.length) {
            div.show();
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I show another div on the 'do something else' position?

Comment: Here, I updated your js fiddle code based of @hsz suggestion. http://jsfiddle.net/QwCQm/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple and crude example:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QwCQm/3/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off">
<div id="volgende">
    <div id="abc-good" class="btn">Nice job! You know your ABC's</div>
    <div id="abc-bad" class="btn">Not there yet...</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#inputId').bind('keyup', function () {
    
    $('#volgende div').hide();
    
    var desiredVal = 'abc';    // what the user SHOULD type
    var divName = this.value;  // what the user DID type
    
    var msgKey = divName == desiredVal ? 'good' : 'bad';
    
    // if the user has typed something, show the message
    if( divName.length > 0 )
        $('#'+desiredVal+'-'+msgKey).show()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try a `change` event. So...

```
$('#inputId').bind('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "[CORRECT_INPUT]") {
        $('#my_incorrect_input_div').show();
    }
});
```